Where does the Medrash quote the Torah differently from the masoretic text?
The Wikipedia page on Midrash says as follows:

Although this material treats the biblical texts as the authoritative word of God, it is clear that not all of the Hebrew Bible was fixed in its wording at this time, as some verses that are cited differ from the Masoretic, and accord with the Septuagint, or Samaritan Torah instead.

Can anyone provide examples of this? What is the rabbinic response to the suggestion that the Torah wasn't "fixed in its wording" as the explanation for the Medrash quoting pesukim that align with "alternative" texts instead of the Torah?

This is probably off-topic, as it represents a completely secular understanding of Medrash that is entirely inconsistent with the Jewish approach.

R Akiva Eiger to Shabbat 55b provides a list of quotations from a bunch of sources, including Midrashim, where their text of Tanach differs from ours. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gilyon_HaShas_on_Shabbat.55b?lang=he

@NT this feels completely on topic to me. The question notes a phenomenon in a Jewish text (referenced in the Wikipedia article) which certainly exists, and asks for more examples as well as rabbinic explanations of it.

@JoelK You have a good source to write an answer!

@YDJ If I get a chance I made do that, but it's a busy time of year, so if anyone else would like to upgrade my comment into an answer, please feel free to do so

Talmud is full of (mostly defective vs. full spelling) examples, where we don't follow the Babylonian sages

Apparently, the Rabbinic Jewish approach or sect doesn't represent all Jewish beliefs schools and views of history. I recommend scholarly books on Hebrew bible textual criticism.

Download or borrow books from archive sites like Anna's archive

You can see some examples in a list I made a few years ago (and update every now and then): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sv-LfYEOpve4N1T5QZ6hB57V4qtnmnR0/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=101460971828417091429&rtpof=true&sd=true. Some of the verses there don't appear at all in Tanach but several do but with some textual variants.

@Harel13 Nice list, more in Sanh. 7a (כי שבע יפול צדיק וקם ורשע יפול באחת) and 108a (ולא נח בהם) and one pointed out here. BK 81b is interesting because it shows that the Gemara knew there was no such verse: ומי כתיב מהיות טוב אל תקרי רע אין כתיב כי האי גוונא
(merged to prevent clutter).

@ba thanks again, I just added those in.

The Tosafos and other mepharshim I have seen say that the Sages were not always careful to quote a verse exactly. So the problem would only be if it is clear they meant to refer to the exact language of the verse.

@JoelK The quotation does much more than note a phenomenon: it gives an explanation that very likely is heretical, in support of a theory of Biblical authorship that is off topic.

@N.T. It's clearly a heretical opinion. It's Wikipedia, I don't know what you expect. I want the examples that serve as the basis for that opinion, and the response to those examples from the frum perspective. Your comment might serve as a good answer to the second half of the question if you can provide sources.

@N.T. if a Medrash misquotes a pasuk, it's valid to ask why. The heresy is only in the assumption that it's an indication that the Torah is not min hashomayim. The fact that I'm asking for the response puts this question squarely in the on topic camp. If you can demonstrate that I'm supporting heresy in my question, then by all means prove it.

This issue is addressed in Tosafos to Shabbos 128a :

ונתן הכסף וקם לו - אין הפסוק כן אלא ויסף חמישית כסף ערכך עליו וקם לו (ויקרא כ״ז:ט״ו) ודרך הש"ס לקצר ולומר בלשון אחר קצר כי ההיא דפרק הדר (עירובין דף סה.) רבי חנינא ביומא דרתח לא מצלי שנאמר בצר אל יורה ובפרק הרואה (ברכות דף נה:) שנאמר כל החלומות הולכים אחר הפה

It is normal for Chazal to not be precise when quoting pesukim. So showing differences in wording does not necessarily indicate that they had a different text.
(This is assuming the issue is not simply a copyist's error.)

I once saw an explanation (and I can't remember the source) that they may have done that deliberately, so as to avoid the potential issur of writing pesukim without sirtut.

While surely this accounts for some of the variation, in context some of it is explicitly being quoted precisely and representing a different text than we have. Famously, Yalkut Shimoni 34 (among other places) writes בתורתו של ר' מאיר מצאו כתוב כתנות אור that in Rabbi Meir's torah scroll it was written כתנות אור not as we have כתנות עור. This is not just a later paraphrase but a explicit variation in a period torah scroll. Plenty of other examples exist where this answer is untenable.

@DoubleAA I said "not necessarily" for a reason, because that covers most cases. The case of בתורתו של ר' מאיר מצאו כתוב כתנות אור is different, because that is explicitly mentioned as a variation that was found, not an indication that the text wasn't set at all. Rather it was set, but they found a variation. (And this is assuming it means his Torah scroll. Some commentators to Medrash Rabbah (Yefeh Toar IIRC) say it refers to R' Meir's chiddushei Torah.)

@DoubleAA We also know there were variations in chaser umalei. The Yerushalmi records finding three authoritative scrolls with an alternate spelling in each. That still goes against the claims of the Wikipedia article.

"Rather it was set, but they found a variation." This sounds to me like a word game.

@DoubleAA It is very simple. For example, the Talmud's text is set, but there are variant readings found in manuscripts. Same here. Later variations do not mean there was not a set original.
